# Calling a Method in a list using EL

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl, el

Let's say I have this code

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<SomeObject>> listOfObjects = new ArrayList<SomeObject>();

public ArrayList<SomeObject> getFirstObject(){
    return listOfObjects.get(0);
}
```

How would I call `getFirstObject()` method inside a JSP using EL or JSTL providing that this method is inside someEntity bean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to call this function via the JSP Expression Language you will need to create a custom expression language function.  Checkout this tutorial: http://blog.idleworx.com/2010/04/custom-tags-and-custom-el-functions-in.html